# Only Zip and City autocomplete within some specific country from google map using Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I would like to try Zip code like 2820 but actual zip code is 28201. Autocomplete should suggest me all the city with Zip Code begin with 2820..with in Germany, Austria and Switzarland. But, the following makes me mad. This suggest results for 2820.. is Charlotte, 28201, USA.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete_geomod.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="geo_autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    $('#location').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
        mapkey: 'ABQIAAAAiGoYY4tPjO31w3GvSYDlwhTkja-vWMQBDJKN05n7ytr7kktZCRT9NcRvD0oiTFnhioSC_8Qg-L3zug', 
        selectFirst: false,
        minChars: 3,
        cacheLength: 50,
        width: 300,
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 330,
        mapsensor : false       
    }).result(function(_event, _data) {
        if (_data) map.fitBounds(_data.geometry.viewport);
    });

    $("map_canvas").hide('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've good result when I add the country code to my google map query. Did you try adding the continent?